# multi node environment (cluster), how to make sure an action executed only once on startup?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, cluster-computing

My application is running on a cluster of 4 nodes. On startup (ServletContextListener) it must execute an SQL script. How to make sure that the SQL is executed only once and not 4 times as each of the nodes will try to execute the same code?

Comment: ServletContextListener method , contextInitialized method will call only once at the time of deployment of application. So query will fire only once

Comment: Except that there are 4 nodes in the cluster, each node is running its own copy of the application so there will be 4 ServletContextListeners executing their contextInitialized methods.

Comment: Let me ask you this, first time until when, what happens if after you stop 1 node and start it again, does that count as a new startup ?

Comment: Good question. I guess from that node's perspective it would be the same start up as any other start up regardless if other nodes are restarted along or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute it exactly once (like scripts that update the database structure) you should use some kind of version field in the database (in the simplest case just a single column/single row table). http://flywaydb.org/ might be a solution for you if you don't want to do it yourself. If you instead just want to ensure that no to instances are running the same script concurrently, you use basically the same idea but instead of using a version field which is alway increased use same kind of boolean lock which you reset after after your script finishes. If you want to implement ist yourself, be sure to handle concurrent access properly. For example instead of `select entry from lock /if entry = 0 update lock set entry = 1` which is non atomic do something like `update lock set entry = 1 where entry = 0/check if number affected rows = 1`

Comment: So whoever sees that lock is 0 sets it to 1 and runs the sql script and everyone who wasn't the first will see 1 and so won't do anything?  When will the lock be reset back to 0?

Comment: Yes, just reset it after your script has finished.

Comment: What if script finishes in a second but nodes start with delay longer than that? First node to start sets the value to 1, starts the script, the script finishes, the value is reset to 0. Second node starts, sees that the value is 0 and kicks off the process again?

Comment: That's the part which depends on your requirements. If you want to excute the script exactly once, use the version approach and do not reset it afterwards.. If you want to avoid multiple instances running the script in parallel, use the flag which is resetted after the script finshes. If you really want to distiguish a cluster startup where one node is just slow from a single node restart, you probably should use some kind of `lastRun` field in addition and to the flag start the job only, if some time has passed. But again, it depends on your requirements.